# How do you make your vanilla Minecraft server like a bukkit server without switching to bukkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I do not want to risk losing my vanilla minecraft server that I spent days working on. On my server, I want to make portals that might take you to a mini game. Also, I want to make a mini game map in my server without spending hours on commands and building.

Comment: you could do that all with commands. And it wouldn't take _hours._ You can also use the same world you originally have, and just use bukkit with it. Go to the bukkit website.

Answer (score 1):

@jacob is right but depending on how big your old world is, you could add it to your WorldEdit schemas and just stick it in a new bukkit world using WorldEdit. Don't do this if it's over about 1500 blocks though, or your server will go pop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a new bukkit server and just copy over your world generation folder (copying/pasting the folders) over over the server's generated world and it should be able to run just fine using that.

Keep in mind, any world generation mods that you incorporate won't be able to work on your already loaded chunks of the world, you'd need to explore further to see any additional world generation.